# How to create Gif .net Core2 , with ImageSharp

Tags: c#, .net, imagesharp

Is the any way to create a gif from some jpegs in .net core2 with ImageSharp?

I could create a gif from some jpegs with Magick.Net, but it does'n t work on Linux.

I wanna do this on Ubuntu 14.

> EDIT

I could create a Gif from Jpegs with ImageSharp. This is my source code:

```
        var ite = fsArray.GetEnumerator(); // fsArray is FileStream Array
        ite.MoveNext();
        using (var image1 = Image.Load(ite.Current.Name))
        {
            image1.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));

            // loop
            while (ite.MoveNext())
            {
                using (var image2 = Image.Load(ite.Current.Name))
                {
                    image2.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
                    image2.Frames.First().MetaData.FrameDelay = interval;
                    image1.Frames.AddFrame(image2.Frames.First());
                }
            }
            msGif = new FileStream("result.gif", FileMode.CreateNew);
            var gifEnc = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Gif.GifEncoder();
            image1.Save(msGif, gifEnc);
            msGif.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a trivial operation... you need to generate an optimal palette for the .gif. There seems to be a "Quantizers" namespace in ImageSharp, though, but I am not familiar with the package and how 8-bit images are handled on it.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I hope this will be cleared

Comment: Please use readable variable names when posting a question. I have no idea what `fs` stands for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Load your two images
2. Add the first frame from the second image (after scaling) as an `ImageFrame<T>` to the `Frames` property on the first image.
3. Save the output image as a gif.

Quantization automatically happens when saving the image as a gif. Currently a separate palette will be generated for each frame.

```cs
using (var image1 = Image.Load(instream1))
using (var image2 = Image.Load(instream2))
{
  image2.Mutate(x => x.Resize(image1.Width, image1.Height));
  image1.Frames.AddFrame(image2.Frames[0]);

  image1.Save(outstream, new GifEncoder());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. I tried this (See my EDIT section for code), but I couldn't create a gif. Because "addImg.Frames.First()" is nothing. addImg has no Frames. why ?

Comment: What are you using? `Image<TPixel>` doesn't have a `Resize` method and hasn't done so since early alphas. 

Make sure you are using the official SixLabors.ImageSharp Nuget package

Comment: You are right. I had mistake to install. After reinstall, I could create a gif, thanks ! But , I couldn't set the DelayTime for it. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: You're looking for `ImageFrame<TPixel>.Metadata.FrameDelay` This is measured in hundredths (1/100) of a second.

Comment: Thank you ! My question is resolved. Thank you for the great helpful !!

Comment: Happy to help :)